# What is Python alternative to Java @AndroidFindBy @iOSFindBy annotations

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I have mobile native application (iOS and Android) that I want to automate using Python - application interaction and logic look similar for iOS and Android. What is the best way to share test logic across mobile platform.

I found a way how JavaClient works - simply use annotations @AndroidFindBy and @iOSFindBy.

Is there alternative for Python? Having many if\else in my code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

***[Dated 7 Jun,2016]***
As of now I don't think this (annotated `By` method) have been implemented for accessing `WebElements` or `MobileElements` in python.

You can go through the [ByClass](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/appium/webdriver/common/mobileby.py), [Appium's WebDriver.py](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py) and the ChangeLog and RoadMap documented at [Appium python client GitHub repository](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py) for more details over it.